# Get the selected value of a dynamically generated drop down in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this form where a user can upload an article and he has the option of adding some coauthors. If he wants to add a coauthor he would click on a button which will dynamically generate a drop down menu containing a list of other users.

The problems is that I am dynamically generating those select menus, so each of them will have a different ng-model.Here is the code from the controller:

```
$scope.numberOfCoauthors = 0;
$scope.addCoauthors = function() {
    $scope.index = "input_" + $scope.numberOfCoauthors;
    console.log("Scope.model : " + $scope.index);
    var $div = $("<p> Coautor: </p> <select ng-model='" + $scope.index + "'" +
            " ng-options='user.username for user in allUsers'  </select>" +
            "<pre> {{ " + $scope.index + " | json }} </pre>")
    var target = angular.element(document.querySelector('#coauthors'));

    angular.element(target).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
        var addedSelect = angular.element(target).scope();
        target.append($compile($div)(addedSelect));
        //$scope.$apply();
      });
    $scope.numberOfCoauthors++;
}

 $scope.getSelectedValues = function () {
     if( $scope.numberOfCoauthors > 0) {
         for(i=0; i<$scope.numberOfCoauthors; i++) {
             var inputName = "input_"+i;
             console.log(inputName);
             console.log($scope.inputName);
         }

     }
 }
```

When I am trying to get the value of **$scope.inputName** I get undefined, so I think those models are not actually added to the scope, but I don't really know how to add them.

Comment: I would recommend scrapping all of that jQuery and adding elements to the DOM from your controller and simply use an ng-repeat with your authors collection which I assume is an array of objects ... if not, then it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{id:1,username:"julien"},{id:2,username:"robert"}];
  
  $scope.coAuthors = [];
  $scope.coAuthor = {};
  
  $scope.addCoauthor = function(){
    $scope.coAuthors.push($scope.coAuthor);
  };
  
  $scope.coAuthorShow = false;

  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="controller">
  <div ng-show="coAuthorShow">
  <div ng-repeat="coA in coAuthors">{{coA.username}}</div>
  <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
      ng-options="user.username for user in users"
      ng-model="coAuthor"></select>
  <button ng-click="addCoauthor()">ADD CoAuthor</button>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="coAuthorShow = !coAuthorShow">Add coAuthors</button>
</div>
```

You can do something like that, create the select and hide him

Comment: This is what I was referring to in my comment above.  Nice job